# Is it possible to merge data frames with different amounts of rows using Perl?

Tags: dataframe, perl

I have a little problem that I can´t solve.

I have two data frames (DF): the first (Main DF) has 8 columns and 45918 rows, the second (Complementary DF) has 4 columns and 97969 rows.
If you want to see the complete DF, here is the link to my GitHub: https://github.com/MauriAndresMU1313/Example_Merge_Dataframes

Here an example that how look like the DF.

Main DF:

```
ID1          ID2         dN          dS          Omega       Label_ID1       Label_ID2       Group
AVP78042     AVP78031    0.0059      0.1188      0.0500      SARSr-bat-CoV   SARSr-bat-CoV   Intra
ATO98108     AVP78031    0.1373      1.4673      0.0936      SARSr-bat-CoV   SARSr-bat-CoV   Intra
ATO98108     AVP78042    0.1371      1.4224      0.0964      SARSr-bat-CoV   SARSr-bat-CoV   Intra
```

Complementary DF:

```
Distance    ID_1        ID_2        Value
DISTANCE    AVP78042.1  ATO98108.1  0.29731
DISTANCE    AVP78042.1  ATO98120.1  0.29281
DISTANCE    AVP78042.1  ATO98132.1  0.33095
```

In this case, my main goal is to merge the complementary´s columns (*ID_1, ID_2* and *Value*) to the main DF. The ID_1 and ID_2 in both cases are the same, however, have a different order.

To do that, I think in to do a match between ID_1 and 2 between both data frames and when the match is true to add the column Value (Complementary DF) to the Main DF. *I think in an "if" condition to do that*.
The problem here maybe is the different amount of rows and the order of the labels (ID_1 and ID_2) between each DF.
Previously, I use a Perl script to merge DF:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw{ say };

sub load {
    my ($file, $table, $phase) = @_;
    open my $in, '<', $file or die "$file: $!";
    while (<$in>) {
        chomp;
        my @columns = split /\t/;
        my $id = join '_', @columns[0, 1];
        die "Duplicate $id."
            if 'first' eq $phase && exists $table->{$id};

        push @{ $table->{$id} }, $columns[2];
        say join "\t", @columns[0, 1], @{ $table->{$id} }
            if 'print' eq $phase;
    }
}

my %table;
my $phase = 'first';
while (my $file = shift @ARGV) {
    load($file, \%table, $phase);
    $phase = 1 == @ARGV ? 'print' : '';
}
```

I think to complete this script to work in my new goal, I need an "if" condition to generate a match between IDs.
Here is an example of a possible output:

```
ID1          ID2         dN          dS          Omega   Value   Label_ID1       Label_ID2       Group
AVP78042     AVP78031    0.0059      0.1188      0.0500 0.29731  SARSr-bat-CoV   SARSr-bat-CoV   Intra
ATO98108     AVP78031    0.1373      1.4673      0.0936    -     SARSr-bat-CoV   SARSr-bat-CoV   Intra
```

I put the "-" in the column Value to show an example of "not match" between ID_1 and ID_2.

I tried different ways, however, I can´t solve the problem yet.

Any suggestion or comment to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After making changes to my input files:

```
Main DF:
ID1          ID2         dN          dS          Omega
AVP78042     AVP78031    0.0059      0.1188      0.0500 
ATO98108     AVP78031    0.1373      1.4673      0.0936 
ATO98108     AVP78042    0.1371      1.4224      0.0964 
...
Complementary DF:
ID1          ID2        Value
AVP78042.1  ATO98108.1  0.29731
AVP78042.1  ATO98120.1  0.29281
...
```

This script merges the columns when it does match between IDs:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file01 = $ARGV[0];
my $file02 = $ARGV[1];
my @content02;

open (B, $file02) or die;
while (my $l1 = <B>) {
  $l1 =~ s/\n//g;
  $l1 =~ s/\r//g;
  $l1 =~ s/^ //g;
  push @content02, $l1 ;
}
close B;

### Running with the first file ()
open (A, $file01) or die;

LINE:
while (my $l2 = <A>) { # From file 1 (ref)
  $l2 =~ s/\n//g;
  $l2 =~ s/\r//g;
  $l2 =~ s/ //g;
  my @matrix_2 = split ("\t", $l2);
  my $two_id_01 = $matrix_2[0]; ### No tiene punto
  my $two_id_02 = $matrix_2[1]; ### No tiene punto

  foreach my $q (@content02) { ### From file 2
    my @matrix_q = split ("\t", $q);
    my $q_id_01 = $matrix_q[0];
    my $q_id_02 = $matrix_q[1];
    my $value = $matrix_q[2];

    if (($q_id_01 =~ /^$two_id_01/) and ( $q_id_02 =~ /^$two_id_02/) ) {
      print "$l2\t$value\n";
      next LINE;
    }
  }
}


close A;

exit;
```

Output:

```
Merge DF (6 columns x 42336 rows) 
ID1          ID2         dN     dS      Omega   Value
ATO98108    AVP78042    0.1371  1.4224  0.0964  0.29731
ATO98120    AVP78042    0.1376  1.2989  0.1060  0.29281
```